# Generar un .exe de un script de python que usa multithreading

Tags: python, hilos, exe

He generado un programa que consiste en una GUI en Tkinter y utilizo la librería multithreading entre otras cosas para no congelar la interfaz. Conozco Pyinstaller, py2exe, Nuitka y cx_freeze pero todos me han generado problemas al empaquetar la librería multithreading. He valorado cambiar esta librería por la librería multiprocessing pero hay hilos de control de procesos (Bucles de PIDs) y otras cosas en constante comunicación entre hilos y sería muy largo de sustituir. ¿Existe alguna alternativa compatible con multithreading para agrupar todo el proyecto en un archivo?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] y a leer [ask]. Sobre tu pregunta, decir que _"te han generado problemas"_ no es la mejor descripción con la que puedas encontrar ayuda en el sitio. Sugiero que edites tu pregunta y añadas los detalles relevantes al problema para que puedas encontrar la ayuda que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Cual es el error que genera? Prueba con la opcion `--debug  --console` para ver que es lo que puede estar sucediendo.

Por otro lado, tkinter no es muy amigable con los threads y no se recomienda utilizarlo en un script en tkinter. De ser posible utilizar el método `after` sobre la ventana Tk para mantener un lazo infinito.

Comment: Esto más que una respuesta es un comentario. No está aportando una solución realmente.

Comment: Con 50 de reputación ya puedes comentar donde quieras.

Comment: He probado a compilarlo con las opciones de --debug all --console pero al ejecutar el .exe la consola desaparece demasiado rápido como para leer lo que sucede.